# Problema com Javascript - combos dependentes em Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

Observem a imagem a baixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso acontece quando ao carregar o combo de categorias para carregar o combo de subcategorias.

Qual é o objetivo?

Ao selecionar o combo de categorias ele irá carregar o combo de subcategorias automaticamente por causa de um arquivo Java script, porém está gerando um erro no arquivo Javascript na linha 55.

A linha 55 do meu arquivo JavaScript é essa abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse projeto se trata do Spring Boot, eu entendo um pouco do spring boot, mas conheço muito pouco de JavaScript, eu que tipo que peguei um código pronto e tentei adaptar-lo.

Aqui está o código JavaScript completo;

```
var Arm = Arm || {};

Arm.ComboCategoria  = (function () {

     function ComboCategoria(){
        this.combo = $('#categoria');
        this.emitter = $({});
        this.on = this.emitter.on.bind(this.emitter);
     }

     ComboCategoria.prototype.iniciar = function () {
        this.combo.on('change', onCategoriaAlterada.bind(this));
    }

     function onCategoriaAlterada() {
        this.emitter.trigger('alterado', this.combo.val());
    }
     return ComboCategoria;

}());

Arm.ComboSubCategoria = (function() {

        function ComboSubCategoria(comboCategoria){
            this.comboCategoria =  comboCategoria;
            this.combo = $('#subcategoria');
            this.imgloading = $('.js-img-loading');
        }

        ComboSubCategoria.prototype.iniciar = function() {
            reset.call(this);
            this.comboCategoria.on('alterado', onCategoriaAlterada.bind(this));
        }   

        function onCategoriaAlterada(evento, codigoCategoria) {
//          console.log('codigo da categória ', codigoCategoria);
            if(codigoCategoria){
                var resposta = $.ajax({
                    url: this.combo.data('url'),
                    method:'GET',
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    data:{'categoria': codigoCategoria},
                    beforeSend: iniciarRequisicao.bind(this),
                    complete: finalizarRequisicao.bind(this)
                });
                resposta.done(onBuscarSubCategoriasFinalizado.bind(this));
            }else {
                reset.call(this);
            }
        }

        function onBuscarSubCategoriasFinalizado(subcategorias) {
            var options = [];

            subcategorias.forEach(function(subcategoria){
                options.push('<option value"' + subcategoria.codigo + '">' + subcategoria.nome + '</option>');
            });
            this.combo.html(options.join(''));
            this.combo.removeAttr('disabled');


            var codigoSubCategoriaSelecionada = this.inputHiddenSubCategoriaSelecionada.val();
            if (codigoSubCategoriaSelecionada) {
                this.combo.val(codigoSubCategoriaSelecionada);
            }

        }


        function reset() {
            this.combo.html('<option value="">Selecione a SubCategoria</option>');
            this.combo.val('');
            this.combo.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

        function iniciarRequisicao() {
            reset.call(this);
            this.imgloading.show();
        }

        function finalizarRequisicao() {
            this.imgloading.hide(); 
        }

        return ComboSubCategoria;
}());

$(function(){

    var comboCategoria = new Arm.ComboCategoria();
    comboCategoria.iniciar();
    var comboSubCategoria = new Arm.ComboSubCategoria(comboCategoria);
    comboSubCategoria.iniciar(); 

});
```

aceito todas as sugestões e imploro por uma ajuda.

qualquer dúvida deixei o meu repositório a baixo para analise.

Esse é meu repositório [CLIQUE AQUI](https://github.com/wladyband/arm/tree/master/arm)

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço Spring Boot por isso vou deixar um exemplo em "pure JS". Voce pode ver rodando tambem [aqui no codepen](https://codepen.io/Sidon/pen/yMpbKg) e [aqui no Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sidon/6m1nf0zu/62/).

```js
// By Sidon | 2017
// Fiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/Sidon/6m1nf0zu/62/
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#brand').change(function() {populateCar()});  
  
    var ford = ['Fiesta', 'Focus', 'Fusion', 'Taurus', 'Mustang'];
    var vw = ['Passat', 'Tiguan', 'Golf', 'Jetta', 'Up']
    var fiat = ['Punto', '500', '500 City', 'Panda', 'Doblô']
    var cars =  {'Ford': ford, 'Volks': vw, 'Fiat': fiat}
    var brands = ['Ford','Fiat', 'Volks']
    populateBrand()
  
  
    function populateBrand() {
        $("#brand").empty();
        $("#brand").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
        $.each(brands, function(v) {
            $('#brand')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", brands[v])
                .text(brands[v]));
        })
    }


    function populateCar(event) {
        brand = $("#brand option:selected" ).text();
        $("#car").empty();
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(cars)) {
            if(k==brand) {
                for (car in cars[brand]) {
                    var opt = document.createElement("option");
                     $('#car')
                         .append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value", cars[brand][car])
                         .text(cars[brand][car]));
                }
            };
        }
    }
 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.inline-inputs select {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 420px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- By Sidon | 2017
Fiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/Sidon/6m1nf0zu/62/ -->
<body>
  <h1>Populate one dropdown based on selection in another.</h1>

    <p>Change the contents of dropdown Car based on the selection in dropdown Brand using javascript:</p>

    <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="brandContainer" class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for "brand">Brand:</label>
                <div class="controls inline-inputs">
                    <select required id="brand"></select>
                    <span class="help-inline"></span>
                </div>   
            </div>
          
            <div id="carContainer" class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for "car">Car:</label>
                <div class="controls inline-inputs">
                    <select required id="car"></select>
                    <span class="help-inline"></span>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: não precisa saber muito sobre Spring Boot para resolver esse problema, o que é necessário mesmo e entender de JavaScript, mesmo com seu exemplo não deu pra ajudar muito, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado

Comment: Que problema vc esta encontrado, meu exemplo é em js puro, ja utilizei em varios contextos, sempre com sucesso. 'Estude' meu exemplo, refaça-o no codepen (é free) ou no jsfidle, se preferir, com seus dados e tenho certeza q vc conseguirá.

Comment: A solução veio de onde nem se maginava! eu fiz uma pequena alteração no meu projeto e com isso resolveu meu problema, como tinha mencionado antes eu fiz o projeto com Spring Boot e nele eu utilizo para mostra as informações contidas no banco o Thymeleaf, o que exatamente eu fiz foi atualizar o ThymeLeaf para a nova versão e incluir o artefato Thymeleaf Extra, e permanecendo com o mesmo código JavaScript ele deu certo. estranho né?